# inequality:$(a+c)(b+d)(ac+bd)+4\ge 3(a+b+c+d)$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> If $a,b,c,d>0$ such that $abcd=1$ prove that $$(a+c)(b+d)(ac+bd)+4\ge 3(a+b+c+d)$$

My first idea was to find counter examples and also check the bahaviour of inequality in the edge cases.Easy to see the equality occurs when $a=b=c=d=1$ However there is a big problem when $a\to 0^+ b\to 0^+,c\to 0^+,d\to \infty$ In this case the RHS $\to \infty$ and the LHS although *appears*  $\to 0$ we see that as $b+d\to \infty$ so we cannot say much.

Mixed variables doesnt help much as we cannot take WLOG $a\ge b\ge c\ge d$

I also tried Holder $$(a+c)(b+d)(bd+ac)\ge {(\sqrt[3]{ab^2d}+\sqrt[3]{ac^2d})}^3=ad{(b^{2/3}+c^{2/3})}^3$$ which  has only complicated it further

Looking forward to solutions without lagranges multiplier.

Comment: It will be easier to prove that $(a+c)(b+d)(2) + 4 ≥ 3(a+b+c+d)$ using AM-GM on just $ac+bd$, which [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a%2Bc%29%28b%2Bd%29*2%2B4-3%28a%2Bb%2Bc%2Bd%29+minimum%2C+abcd%3D1) says still holds true for all $a,b,c,d$ satisfying the condition.

Comment: @TobyMak thats a nice observation

Comment: @TobyMak: Unless I made an error, the stronger inequality does *not* hold for $a=c=x$, $b=d=1/x$ with $x \ne 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ac=x\geq1\geq\frac{1}x=bd.$ So if $a+c=2q$  and $b+d=2s,$ then $q\geq\sqrt x$  and $s\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt x}.$ The inequality writes as
$$s\left(2q\left(x+\frac{1}x\right)-3\right)+2-3q\geq0,$$
which we may regard as an affine function of varible $s,$ strictly increasing, for the rest of the elements fixed. It remains to prove
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\cdot\left(2q\left(x+\frac{1}x\right)-3\right)+2-3q\geq0.$$
It's trivial to prove that this one is a strictly increasing affine function of variable $q.$ So we need to prove that
$$2\left(x+\frac{1}x\right)-3\left(\sqrt x+\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\right)+2\geq0,$$
which is obvious since $\sqrt x+\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\geq2.$ Done!

Comment: I looked and yes, I indeed am.

Comment: Ah I asked because i saw the same solution in AOPS ,I just wanted to make sure someone was not copying his(your) work

Comment: Can you explain how $$\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\cdot\left(2q\left(x+\frac{1}x\right)-3\right)+2-3q\geq0.$$ is increasing?

Comment: Of course. Because the coefficient of $q$  is strictly positive (by a trivial calculus).

Comment: But I get the coefficient of q to be Is $$\frac{2(x+\frac{1}{x})}{\sqrt{x}}-3>0$$?

Comment: The right question is:
$$t+\frac{1}{t^3}>\frac{3}2,\left(\forall\right) t\geq1?$$

Comment: Thank you ! I have accepted As i felt this is far easier than the other one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119325/discussion-between-user120123-and-albus-dumbledore).

Answer (score 1):

WLOG assume that $bd\ge 1$ and $ac\le 1$. The inequality rewrites as
$$(a+c)((b+d)(ac+bd)-3)+4\ge 3(b+d).$$
AM-GM and $bd\ge 1$ yield
$$(b+d)(ac+bd)-3\ge 2\sqrt{bd}\cdot 2\sqrt{acbd}-3 \ge 2\cdot 2-3=1>0,$$
hence by AM-GM
$$(a+c)((b+d)(ac+bd)-3) \ge 2\sqrt{ac}((b+d)(ac+bd)-3) = 2(b+d)((ac)^{3/2}+(bd)^{1/2})-6(bd)^{-1/2}.$$
Hence it is enough to prove that
$$2(b+d)((ac)^{3/2}+(bd)^{1/2}-\frac 32) + 4 \ge 6(ac)^{1/2} .$$
Using AM-GM again we obtain $$(ac)^{3/2}+(bd)^{1/2} \ge 4\sqrt[4]{(ac)^{3/2}\cdot \left(\frac{(bd)^{1/2}}{3}\right)^3}=4\cdot 3^{-3/4}>\frac 32,$$
hence by AM-GM
$$2(b+d)((ac)^{3/2}+(bd)^{1/2}-\frac 32) \ge 4(bd)^{1/2}\left((ac)^{3/2}+(bd)^{1/2}-\frac 32\right) = 4ac+4bd-6(bd)^{1/2}$$
and we are left to prove that
$$4ac+4bd+4\ge 6(ac)^{1/2} + 6(bd)^{1/2}.$$
This follows from AM-GM:
$$4ac+4bd+4\ge 3ac+3bd+6 = 3ac+3 + 3bd+3 \ge 6\sqrt{ac}+6\sqrt{bd}$$

Comment: Thank you! It was not as easy as I thought it would be....

Comment: It seems your answer is become famous , someone has attached your answer in [aops](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h2438697_interesting_inequality)

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Nice to hear that!

Comment: :) your idea is definitely very crafty